# Storing sensitive data with WebApi and SQL Server

Tags: c#, encryption, asp.net-web-api, cryptography

I know that its been something common asking about Cryptography and in some cases it is relative the way that it should be. I'm not a Expertise of Encryption but I'm trying to create something that requires a manipulate Credit Cards information and personal too. Currently I'm using WebApi and after researching about it, I found this method the "reliable", at least it seems. So this could be my Main Encryption base on your's Experience on this matter ? It is Rijndael!

This is my code :

```
public class Encryption
{
    internal const string Inputkey = "A GUID";

    public static string EncryptRijndael(string text, string salt)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("text");

        var aesAlg = NewRijndaelManaged(salt);

        var encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
        var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
        using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
        {
            swEncrypt.Write(text);
        }

        return Convert.ToBase64String(msEncrypt.ToArray());
    }
    public static bool IsBase64String(string base64String)
    {
        base64String = base64String.Trim();
        return (base64String.Length % 4 == 0) &&
               Regex.IsMatch(base64String, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\+/]*={0,3}$", RegexOptions.None);
    }
    public static string DecryptRijndael(string cipherText, string salt)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cipherText))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");

        if (!IsBase64String(cipherText))
            throw new Exception("The cipherText input parameter is not base64 encoded");

        string text;

        var aesAlg = NewRijndaelManaged(salt);
        var decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
        var cipher = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

        using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipher))
        {
            using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                {
                    text = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        return text;
    }
    private static RijndaelManaged NewRijndaelManaged(string salt)
    {
        if (salt == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("salt");
        var saltBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt);
        var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Inputkey, saltBytes);

        var aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
        aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);
        aesAlg.IV = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.BlockSize / 8);

        return aesAlg;
    }
}
```

And for the salt, I always pass a new Guid.

```
var SALT = Guid.NewGuid().toString();
Security.Encryption.Encryption.Encrypt(DATA, SALT)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a question in there someplace? Read the post twice and not seeing it.

Comment: I'm showing my code for Encryption and asking if this is a good solution. "So this could be my Main Encryption base on your's Experience on this matter ? It is Rijndael!"

Comment: A couple things... First, unless you are using a .Net Framework prior to 3.5, I wouldn't use RijndaelManaged, I'd use AesCryptoServiceProvider. The reason is that AesCryptoServiceProvider wraps the NIST certified FIPS compliant algorithm. This may not be important now, but if in the future you require FIPS compliance, you are ready. Second, since you are using this over the web, I'd use UTF8Encoding instead of ASCIIEncoding. UTF8 is the more common encoding over the internet. Past that, I don't see anything that screams "bad practice". Long as it is working you should be fine.

Comment: @Kevin Did the IV being derived from the same password as the key not strike you as bad practice?  IVs should always be randomly generated.  In this case, multiple encryption operations using the same key will also use the same IV, which makes the IV predictable.  This encryption code should not be used until that is fixed.  Additionally, there is no authentication, so anyone can modify the data and the receiver wouldn't know.

Comment: @LukePark so, I should create a random key to replace a IV, about the authentication, you talking about whether the user access this code without validation, because each user needs to have a Token to access this Controller and then Crypt! If is not, would you help me to fix the code? thanks!

Comment: @NathielBarros Your terminology is a bit mixed up I think.  The IV and the Key have literally nothing to do with each other.  The way you are creating the key is **good**, e.g. the use of `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`.  But deriving your IV from this is **bad**.  You should generate a new IV each and every time you call `EncryptRijndael`.  And by authentication, I mean that if you encrypt something, and then someone modifies the ciphertext without you knowing, and then you decrypt it, the data you decrypt will be incorrect and you won't know.  Use an HMAC to solve this issue.

Comment: Current accepted practice is to generate a new IV for each encrypt, make the IV the first 16 bytes of the output data followed by the encrypted data. Keep in mind that the IV is NOT considered a secret value. Then at the decryption end you get the IV from the data (first 16 bytes). Procedurally, there is also nothing wrong with designating a fixed IV for both sides to use then exchange them as you would a fixed key.

Comment: @Kevin There **is** something wrong with using a fixed IV.  An IV should be **unpredictable**.  If it is fixed, it isn't unpredictable.

Comment: @LukePark You're preaching to the choir on that one. I don't like it either, and don't use that in my implementations, however, according to accepted practice, it is just as valid to treat the IV as a second secret value and exchange it along with the key, allowing use of a fixed IV value.

Comment: @Kevin Uhhh... can you please cite your source for "according to accepted practice, it is just as valid to treat the IV as a second secret value... allowing use of a fixed IV value."?

Comment: @LukePark To be honest, I had to look it up again and it turns out, I had misread something... It said if you are using single use keys, you can use a fixed IV.

Comment: @Kevin Thought it might be something like that!  Thanks for double checking.